White border around app icon after adapting to the iOS 18 style
I'm redesigning an app icon and using the Xcode interface to change it for my app. The problem is, although the image has no white border and the image size is exactly how Xcode wants it (1024 pt), the app icon gets unwanted white borders when the app is installed on the phone. Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?
enter image description here
Xcode Assets:

icon appearance on the phone (see white borders):


My guess is that your icon has transparent edges.
I was able to reproduce the problem by using an icon which only filled the area 1000x1000. Although the image itself was 1024x1024, the border was transparent:

The fact that it has a transparent border is not apparent when viewing in the asset library in Xcode:

When changed to an image that fills the full area 1024x1024, the problem is resolved:

